# Primefaces datatable sort not working properly

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm doing project in primefaces. I included the data table and sort order. when I click the icon it will not working.

```
I tried the below code:

<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtSortView.cars1}">
    <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{car.id}">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
            </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your **p:dataTable** inside **h:form** tag.

```
<h:form id="carForm">
    <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtSortView.cars1}">
        <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{car.id}">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

You can check this from [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/sort.xhtml) .

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you saw me your `xhtml` file and class represent 'Bean' ?

Comment: You got the solution or not ?

Comment: Please saw me your **Complete files** (like `.xhtml`, `.java` etc..) related to your work.